# Move scrollbar button out of track

Tags: css, frontend, scrollbar, transform, translate

does anybody know any option to move the scrollbar buttons out of the track? I'm trying translate() but it doesn't work. I would like to put them as a down and up arrow in the top and bottom center of a vertical group of thumb pictures.

Thank you very much,
Miguel Gisbert

```css
ul.product-images{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.product-images::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 4px;
}
.product-images::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background: #f1f1f1;
}
.product-images::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background: #888;
border-radius: 4px;
}
.product-images::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
background: #555;
}
.product-images::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    transform: translate(-50px, 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-1 js-qv-mask mask pr-0 scroll">
      <ul class="product-images js-qv-product-images">
                  <li class="thumb-container">
            img
          </li>
                  <li class="thumb-container">
            img
          </li>
                  <li class="thumb-container">
            img
          </li>
                  <li class="thumb-container">
            img
          </li>
                  <li class="thumb-container">
            img
          </li>
                  <li class="thumb-container">
            img
          </li>
                  <li class="thumb-container">
            img
          </li>
                  <li class="thumb-container">
            img
          </li>
                  <li class="thumb-container">
            img
          </li>
                  <li class="thumb-container">
            img
          </li>
                  <li class="thumb-container">
            img
          </li>
                  <li class="thumb-container">
            img
          </li>
                  <li class="thumb-container">
            img
          </li>
              </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just created new scroll up & down buttons with jquery

```
// Scroll up & down for thumb product pictures
$('.scroll-up-button').on('click', function() {
    var y = $('.thumb-container-parent').scrollTop(); 
    $('.thumb-container-parent').scrollTop(y - 100); // up 100px
});
$('.scroll-down-button').on('click', function() {
    var y = $('.thumb-container-parent').scrollTop(); 
    $('.thumb-container-parent').scrollTop(y + 100); // down 100px
});
```